# Testing a motorcycle ignition coil and spark plug

Tags: honda, motorcycle, wiring, ignition-coil, points

Here is an image for reference:

[image]

I am attempting to test this ignition coil and spark plug. How do I go about connecting this to its corresponding 6v battery to get it to fire.

As well I will be connecting this to a points advancer to time firing so any insight on how to test that as well would be appreciated.

Comment: The coil frame needed to be connected to the battery ground AND so does the body (metal) of the spark plug - otherwise there in nowhere for the spark to go. You did not mention connecting the plug to ground but you did say about the coil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frame of the coil will be connected to the battery ground as well as the body of the spark plug.

Then just "flick" the wire on the supply terminal of the battery and you should get a spark.

Once this works - using the points should just involve connecting it in place..

Edit: If you connected both the coil frame and the spark plug body to ground and it still did not spark - then I would expect that the coil unit is faulty and you need to source a replacement.

Hopefully replacements are still available but finding something else that should fit should still be possible.

Edit 2: Back in the day we used to use simple timing lights - just a strobe light that was triggered by the spark and ran off the battery - this enabled one to see when the spark was occurring. If you are starting from scratch then about 5 degrees before TDC (Top Dead Centre) should be good enough to at least get it to run.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and I'm seeing sparks coming off of the positive lead and the wire on the coil, though nothing is coming through the spark plug. Is either my plug or coil bad?

Comment: As well the coil has 30k ohm resistance end to end and the spark plug has 80ish k ohms negative to positive and 0ohm negative to negative.

Comment: Finally got it visibly working by having the engine head withing arcing distance near the sparking gap on the plug